# Confusing array out of bounds on game board

Tags: java, arrays

This is a method in a code for a slightly more complex type of tic tac toe. The problem is, whenever the computer tries to make a move, it gives an array out of bounds -1 error, which is really confusing me because I made sure to specify in the code that it won't do that.

```
    public void computerMove()
    {
       boolean moveMade=false;
       while(!moveMade)
       {                                                                                                                                                                   
          int i = (int)(Math.random()*5);
          int j = (int)(Math.random()*4);
          int p = (int)(Math.random()*5+1); 
          //whether the piece will move up, down, left or right
           if (grid[i][j].getText().equals("0")){
             if (p==1&&grid[i+1][j].getText().equals("")
             &&i<3&&moveMade==false) 
             //here i specify when i<3 to make sure it wont try to go off the board
              {
                grid[i][j].setText("");
                grid[i+1][j].setText("0");
                turn++; checkXHorizontal(); check0Horizontal(); 
                checkXVertical(); check0Vertical(); checkXDF();
                check0DF(); checkXDB(); check0DB();
                whoseTurn.setText("Player's Turn");
                moveMade=true;
             }
             else if (p==2&&grid[i][j+1].getText().equals("")
             &&j<3&&moveMade==false)
             {
                grid[i][j].setText("");
                grid[i][j+1].setText("0");
                turn++; checkXHorizontal(); check0Horizontal(); 
                checkXVertical(); check0Vertical(); checkXDF(); 
                check0DF(); checkXDB(); check0DB();
                whoseTurn.setText("Player's Turn");
                moveMade=true;
             }
             else if (p==3&&grid[i][j-1].getText().equals(""
             )&&j>0&&moveMade==false)
             {
                grid[i][j].setText("");
                grid[i][j-1].setText("0");
                turn++; checkXHorizontal(); check0Horizontal(); 
                checkXVertical(); check0Vertical(); checkXDF(); 
                check0DF(); checkXDB(); check0DB();
                whoseTurn.setText("Player's Turn");
                moveMade=true;
             }
             else if (p==4&&grid[i-1][j].getText().equals("")&&
             i>1&&moveMade==false)
             {
                grid[i][j].setText("");
                grid[i-1][j].setText("0");
                turn++; checkXHorizontal(); check0Horizontal(); 
                checkXVertical(); check0Vertical(); checkXDF();
                check0DF(); checkXDB(); check0DB();
                whoseTurn.setText("Player's Turn");
                moveMade=true;
             }
             else {
                computerMove(); 
             }
          }
       }
```

Comment: Can you paste a stacktrace? At what like does the error occur?

Comment: That's just too much code to expect us to wade through. Please cut it down to a [mcve].

Comment: How should we find what your problem is in this wall of text?

Comment: I did specify the method the problem was located in, and it seems like what you are asking for is that so how do I post code as a comment, I just made this account and I'm not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do

```
 else if (p==3&&grid[i][j-1].getText().equals(""
             )&&j>0&&moveMade==false)
```

and

```
else if (p==4&&grid[i-1][j].getText().equals("")&&
             i>1&&moveMade==false)
```

`grid[i][j-1]` and `grid[i-1][j]`could be out of range because java tests them before `j>0` and `i>1` respectively.

try to move them at the **beginning of the if clause**, in this way

```
else if (p==3&&j>0&&grid[i][j-1].getText().equals(""
                 )&&moveMade==false)
```

and

```
else if (p==4&&i>1&&grid[i-1][j].getText().equals("")&&moveMade==false)
```